# Does SearchFacesbyImage really cost the same no matter how many faces are in the collection?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I think I already have the answer to this via the documentation, but it seems too good to be true, so I thought I'd ask here - sadly Amazon's tech support tier costs $30 a month and I only have the one question.

Our use case is that our customers create small collections of around 30 faces to be used in future recognition in bigger photo sets. However, each customer would have many collections of 30 faces so would have to scan each photo set multiple times to find all the matches. My understanding was that calling SearchFacesbyImage would incur a larger cost the more faces were stored in the collection.

Is it really true that each SearchFacesbyImage call would cost the same amount if the collection contained 30 faces or 20,000,000 faces? This seems odd to me but perhaps our use case is just so small that it doesn't matter, and the huge limit is imposed for significantly larger organisations.